# Using select distinct with IF condition

Tags: mysql

How can I ignore the `is_enrolled` field from distinct? This is the query:

```
select DISTINCT
`courses`.*, IF(course_enrollments.user_id=12, TRUE, FALSE) as is_enrolled 
from `courses` 
inner join `course_time_periods` on `course_time_periods`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` 
inner join `org_time_periods` on `time_period_id` = `org_time_periods`.`id` 
left join `course_groups` on `course_time_periods`.`id` = `course_groups`.`course_period_id` 
left join `course_enrollments` on `course_groups`.`id` = `course_enrollments`.`group_id`
where `org_time_periods`.`started_at` <= "2017-08-12 12:39:05" 
    and `org_time_periods`.`finished_at` >= "2017-08-12 12:39:05" 
    and `courses`.`is_active` = true 
    and `courses`.`organization_id` = 2 
    and `course_enrollments`.`deleted_at` is null
```

This duplicating one course because it's enrolled, so it returns the first row with `is_enrolled` as `true`and next one as `false`.

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting as a result? When you say ignore is_enrolled and you accually have one row with true and one with false you need to decide which one to keep.

Comment: I added a screenshot for the current response. You can see that the ourse N° 6 is duplicated and after verifying DB I can see that user is enrolled to course, so I would like to eliminate the `is_enrolled: false` row

Comment: There is no duplicate in the table. Yes you have 2 rows with id 6 but is_enrolled is not same on them. So you need to come up with a rule for those cases. e.g. "When two rows with same id and diffrent is_enrolled keep the one that has is_enrolled = 1"

Comment: Or you need to figure out why you have two rows with diffrent is_enrolled. You cant exclude anything from DISTINCT without removing it from the SELECT colum list. Because the RDBMS wont know which row to keep.

Comment: Thanks, I will check again, maybe the query is wrong. But I was thinking about how distinct based on a specific field not the whole row

Comment: There is no logical way to do a distinct on specific columns because the db engine won't know what to do with the other columns. Like your is_enrolled, you have true and false. How should the rdbms know which one to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to generate a list of all courses, plus a note as to which of those courses a specific user is enrolled in.

If that's the case, try changing the query as follows:

```
    select DISTINCT
    `courses`.*, IF(`course_enrollments`.`group_id` IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) as is_enrolled 
    from `courses` 
    inner join `course_time_periods` on `course_time_periods`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` 
    inner join `org_time_periods` on `time_period_id` = `org_time_periods`.`id` 
    left join `course_groups` on `course_time_periods`.`id` = `course_groups`.`course_period_id` 
    left join `course_enrollments` on (    `course_groups`.`id` = `course_enrollments`.`group_id`
                                       AND `course_enrollments.user_id` = 12
                                      )
    where `org_time_periods`.`started_at` <= "2017-08-12 12:39:05" 
        and `org_time_periods`.`finished_at` >= "2017-08-12 12:39:05" 
        and `courses`.`is_active` = true 
        and `courses`.`organization_id` = 2 
        and `course_enrollments`.`deleted_at` is null
```

As far as I can tell, your left joins only exist to check to see if the `user_id` in question showed up in a `course_enrollments` row. So, I modified the join to `course_enrollments` so that *only* rows with the indicated `user_id` would be returned by the join.

Then, instead of checking for `user_id = 12`, we simple test for whether a row was returned from `course_enrollments`. If a row was returned, then the user you're interested in is enrolled; otherwise, they are not enrolled.

Note: the code is untested.

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing part. It only needed a couple fresh eyes to help

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot exclude a column in a distinct list unless you remove it from the select list.

In the case that there are two records, one true and one false, which record do you want to keep?  You can min() or max() to keep the one you want and then the distinct list can return just one row.